# Spell check should ignore underscore variable names in MS Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, documentation, spell-checking

Is there a good way to have MS Word 2010 spellcheck ignore variable names in technical documents (e.g.: like words with underscores)?

I shouldn't have to load a data dictionary to accomplish this, or add these words to a dictionary in MS Word.

I tried creating a style "code", but it changed the font to all bold, or to not-bold, which was not what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You can force Word-Spell-Checker to omit certain text by defining a Character Style with (only) property "Do not check spelling or grammar", and apply that style to any text you want Spelling checker to omit. To do this follow the steps below:

1. Select any character that has no special formatting (e.g. it has style as Normal or body text)
2. On the Review ribbon -> Language -> Set Proofing Language
   [image]
3. In the dialog, check the box for "Do not check spelling or grammar" and click OK.
   [image]
4. On the Home ribbon -> (in Styles group) click More drop down (Quick Styles gallery) -> Create a Style

   [image]
5. In the dialog, give a sensible name (e.g. NoSpellingCheck) -> click Modify (button)
   [image]
6. In the dialog, 
   o change the "Style type" to "Character", 
   o check the "New documents based on this template" (option at the bottom) and 
   o verify that the definitions (below the preview) include "Do not check spelling or grammar" and "Based on: Default Paragraph Font". Click OK.

   [image]
7. When you exit Word, you may be prompted to save changes to the Normal.dotm template, select "Yes", and that's it.

Now, whenever you have text that you want the spell checker to omit, apply the "NoSpellingChecker" style you created and it will be ignored by Word's spell checker, without affecting the appearance of your text.

Comment: You can actually set the no-spell-check directly from the *Modify Style* control. It's under Format --> Language.

Answer (score 2):

Another - quicker way could be to simply run a macro that instructs Microsoft Word to ignore "Spellings & Grammar" checks for the selected text. Here is the VBA code which you can save in your Normal.dot file:

> ```
> Sub IgnoreSpellingAndGrammar()
>     Selection.NoProofing = True
> End Sub
> ```

Tip: To run this macro quickly, you can 1) either add a shortcut-icon on the "Quick access toolbar" OR 2) add a hotkey/keyboard shortcut such as "Alt+i" (which further saves time.)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no good way to tell Word directly to skip over words with underscores (see FrameMaker for how it's *supposed* to be done). However, you can use the [language-spellchecking feature in Word to do a similar trick](https://superuser.com/questions/256247/word-disable-spell-checker-for-a-paragraph), apparently.  Just assign your "code" paragraph tag to a language you don't use, and then set that language to be skipped in spellchecking.